# How to restrict 'move' to certain divs using dnd-list (javascript/angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I'm using 'Drag & Drop List' (http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple).

The default behaviour is that a click'n'drag anywhere on an `<li>` element will cause that `<li>` to move.

Is there a way to restrict that behaviour so that the user needs to click on a particular sub-element of the `<li>`?

I've set up a plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/6mOkqRuY4aXY3NUE5W7F?p=preview) where each `<li>` contains two divs, thus:

```
   <ul dnd-list="models.lists.A">
    <li ng-repeat="item in models.lists.A"
        dnd-draggable="item"
        dnd-moved="models.lists.A.splice($index, 1)"
        dnd-effect-allowed="move"
        dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
        ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}">
      <div class="theheader">A header</div>
      <div class="thebody">{{item.label}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to restrict the click'n'drag behaviour to the theheader div only, and if I click in the thebody div then nothing happens.

(Reason for this is that in my actual project I've got edit boxes in the `<li>` and if you click on the edit box and drag to select the edit box contents you end up moving the entire `<li>` - a bad user experience!)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer...  It's in the github notes on the project.  Add attribute dnd-nodrag to a new div surrounding the actual content and add attribute dnd-handle to theheader div, thus

```
<body class="simpleDemo" ng-controller="SimpleDemoController">
<ul dnd-list="models.lists.A">
    <li ng-repeat="item in models.lists.A"
        dnd-draggable="item"
        dnd-moved="models.lists.A.splice($index, 1)"
        dnd-effect-allowed="move"
        dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
        ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}">
      <div dnd-nodrag>
        <div class="theheader" dnd-handle>A header</div>
        <div class="thebody">Body for {{item.label}}</div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/TI1wjkkurrAVNAiutyU4?p=preview

Now dragging on the blue header will move the `<li>`, dragging anywhere else does nothing...